# Binary file loading leading to data loss

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am attempting to read data from a file that has been pre-formatted in order to pass it straight into a vertex buffer. When reading files above a certain size (somewhere above 1152 bytes, but less than 92,160 bytes), it fails. It writes a number of values from the file to the allocated memory, before not setting the rest, leaving them with the value -431602080 which appears to be a CRT value representing clean memory ([SO Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155491/what-does-431602080-000000-value-in-glmmodel-vertex-means). The number of values that it successfully writes appears to vary with filesize.

I have investigated whether I was exceeding allocation limits, however it does not appear to be this. I have checked to ensure the allocation is not failing for other reasons. I have read the data into a vector that was previously filled with values in order to see whether it was manually writing the value -431602080, however the previous values remain indicating it is just failing to write the memory.

```
void Mesh::LoadMeshFromFile(DXManager* dxPtr, LPCSTR fileName, int ID)
{
    std::fstream f(fileName, std::ios_base::in);
    short vertexStride = sizeof(Vertex);                            //Gets the stride per vertex
    long fileLength = f.seekg(0, std::ios::end).tellg();            //Gets the byte count
    float vertexCount = (float)fileLength / (float)vertexStride;    //Calculates the vertex count

    if (vertexCount == (int)vertexCount)    //Ensures there are no incomplete vertices
    {
        if (vertexCount > 134217727 || vertexCount * vertexStride > 2147483647)
        {
            //Alloc will definitely fail.
            //Throw an error
        }
        else
        {
            char* vertices = new __nothrow char[(int)fileLength];
            if (vertices == NULL)
            {
                //Allocation failed
                //Throw an error
            }
            else
            {
                //Read all vertices directly into the array and build the buffer
                f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
                f.read(vertices, fileLength);
                BuildBuffer(dxPtr, (Vertex*)vertices, vertexCount);     
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //1 or more incomplete vertices.
    }
}
```

Below is an example output. The problem does not occur with certain files and appears to be file size dependant. The position that the data loss occurs is not constant and also appears to vary due to file size.

[image]

As you can see, the data is valid until the 4th entry, partially through the line.
Hopefully someone is able to shed some light on what is happening.

Comment: You are using Floats...Why? Surely a long is better in most cases...

Comment: The data requires decimals, and is used in XMMATRIX operations which are built on the FLOAT typedef.

Comment: You are using float not FLOAT...Could that be worth checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a binary file, you need to specify ios::binary (default is text for fstream)

Comment: That appeared to be the problem. It is loading in perfectly now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The largest consecutive integer (counting from zero) that you can successfully represent in a single precision `float` is 2^24, or **16,777,216**.  Your file length could easily exceed this size that a `float` can represent accurately.

Use `long` or `int` for integer values, and type-cast to `float` when required.  Not the other way around.

If you try to read more bytes than actually exist in your file, due to `float`-to-`long` conversion errors in `f.read(vertices, fileLength);`, you will not read the data properly - and get a possible corruption.

I would declare your variables as:

```
long vertexStride = sizeof(Vertex);                    //Gets the stride per vertex
long fileLength = f.seekg(0, std::ios::end).tellg();   //Gets the byte count
float vertexCount = fileLength / vertexStride;          //Calculates the vertex count
```

Also, clear the filestream in case the EOF marker is not cleared by `seekg`.
Use `f.clear();` before the seek to the beginning.

Also - again - you should trap the return value from ALL your filestream functions...They are likely failing and you are not stopping to examine why...See the code formatting in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264764/seekg-function-fails) on SO

Comment: Sorry I understand what you mean by using floats now. I have amended the variables to use better suited data types rather than float, although this was not the current issue as the files I am attempting to load are significantly smaller than the capacity of both floats and longs.

Comment: Sorry, for brevity of the code snippet, I removed the file checks, as because I was partially recieving data, I didn't think they were relevant to the question. I am however checking to see if the file has loaded and I check to see whether the second seek is successful. Unfortunately f.clear() doesn't appear to have worked, and I'm still only able to load in partial data.

Comment: @ZacHoward-Smith Glad that holtavolt could help you :)  Welcome to Stack Overflow, have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for your all your help.